# Can I use the coordinating conjunction "and" in the single word question "And?"?

Tags: conjunctions

Is it correct to ask the following question: "And?", when you ask for more answers to avoid the repetition of the full question you are referring to. For example, in the following conversation:

> **Arnold**: What colors can you see in this picture?
>   **Billy**: Brown.
>   **Arnold**: And?
>   **Billy**: Yellow.
>   **Arnold**: And?
>   **Billy**: Grey.

Comment: Yes, this is normal usage for conversational English.

Answer (score 2):

*And* is used in conversational English when the person who is listening is expecting the other person to say more, as in your case and in the following one.

> **A**: I saw Michelle.
>   **B**: And?
>   **A**: She said she misses you and she feels stupid for what she did.
>   **B**: She could have thought of that before doing what she did.
>   **A**: Yes, but she is really sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 'And?' is an elliptical question. Merriam Webster defines elliptical as marked by extreme economy of speech or writing.